# What can a man that owns land for agriculture be called without using "farmer"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Does anybody know?

Comment: It depends whether he actually works the land or not, or if he rents it to someone else to work.

Comment: @Benjol give me whatever you have, any version will help me

Comment: These days? You could call them "broke", despite their 18 hour days...

Comment: @Laurel - Please don't edit the tag "single-word-requests" into an old question without adding an example sentence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- If he works the land, you could call it an "**agricultural tenant**" (also "tenant farmer" , but you don' t want the word "farmer" in there)
- If he owns the lands, "**Agricultural Landlord**"

The terms "tenant" and "landlord" are good candidates, but can also be applied for other kind of real estates than farms. Hence the "agricultural" qualifier.

Comment: Careful with these though. It will end up very stitled if you do not watch out.

Comment: An "argricultural tenant" does not own the land by definition. 
An "agricultural landlord" lets the land out to be farmed but doesn't farm it himself. If he owns it and it's used for farming I would go with "agricultural landowner"

Comment: Whether they are a tenant or not seems secondary to me. If you want an alternative to "farmer", I would prefer words like "grower", "rancher", "grazier".

Answer (score 6):

agriculturalist, grower, rancher, market gardener, agrarian......

Comment: An Australian wheat producer is always a "grower". It is a sign of city-slicker ignorance to call them a "farmer".

Answer (score 5):

"Agricultural/Rural Land owner" or just "Land owner" is also an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

"Agricultural landowner" is your best bet.

"Agricultural tenant" implies that he rents the land FROM someone else (and is thus not the owner). "Agricultural landlord" implies that he rents it TO someone else, which may not be the case you are looking for. A landlord is a landowner but a landowner is not necessarily a landlord.

Answer (score 0):

I like Ross's suggestions, and I think some answers are getting hung up on a secondary issue, land ownership, when the answer should be focussing on the primary thing, that this person does agricultural work.

I would suggest the following in additon to Ross's answer:

**producer**, **grazier**, **pastoralist**, **orchardist**